# Is there any reason not to use classification instead of regression when looking for ranges?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression

In the case I want to predict only ranges from a continuous value, is there any reason to use regression instead of classification ? Could it depend on the type of model I am using (neural network, decision tree, bayesian, ...) ?

**Example**

Let say I have a dataset with images. Each image has one human on it and is labeled with his/her height. Now I am only interested in predicting height ranges, for instance these four classes *[ A, B, C, D ] = [ <150, 150-170, 170-190, >190 ] (in cm)*. Is there any reason why one of the two following approaches should lead to better performances ?

- **case 1**: using *regression* - First create and fit a model that predicts the exact height from an image, then simply gives its associated height range.
- **case 2**: using *classification* - First label all the images with the wanted ranges (=classes), then create and fit a classifier to predict this height range.

*Note*: I am wondering if there is a general answer to this question, not only to this example

**EDIT**

As @n1tk pointed out, in the post [Performance of CNN based deep models with number of classes](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/43366/performance-of-cnn-based-deep-models-with-number-of-classes), the question is answered if we think about increasing the number of classes. In my question, I am wondering about ***regression* vs classification**. So try to fit a continuous value vs ranges from this value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Performance of CNN based deep models with number of classes](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/43366/performance-of-cnn-based-deep-models-with-number-of-classes)

Comment: In the post you suggest, it seems the question is about the number of classes, so it is is only about classification, am I wrong ? So if a neural network is used (as in the post), one hot encoded vectors would probably be used for the labeling and the backpropagation. Here I was more wondering about *regression vs classification*. It might be related but it is not obvious to me.

Comment: stackoverflow is full will comparison of logistic vs OLS. You point as interval there and is nothing else than a category because you predict [A, B, C, D] ... one way is to transform Y with logit and fit GLM. here is another post related to logit vs OLS on time series data https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/201299/80330

Comment: to answer better your question look at assumptions of each regression and will point in right direction ... going to what you try to do: you look for probability of an event to be in that range vs actual continuous value with OLS ... and going to task in CNN you are looking for prob of an event when you look at activation function for neurons (perceptron and logit info will help to understand first link)

Comment: I see your point and I agree. So both should lead in the same performances. Thank you for your answer

Comment: GLM and logistic yes, but need to look that predictions will be outside [0,1] for GLM so just think of interpreting.

Comment: Also I do not see a point for predicting actual value then “map” to range “class” when you can “predict” probability of that event in what class does belong :) because this is what logit is actually performing in binary and multi-class like in your case ... first link was a bit of “generalization” when marked the question but all comments is extension of logit vs OLS.

Comment: Me neither, that's why I asked to be sure I did not miss something :). Just to be sure, it should be the case also with neural networks ? (you said yes for GLM and logistic only)

Comment: same scope the yes because activation function will do same ... neurons "firing" ...

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifying and confirming that to me !

Comment: @n1tk just to know, will you write an answer ? it might be useful for other users, don't you think ? Otherwise I would (and cite you of course). Thanks

Comment: Yes, will do today and reference some papers to make robust answer so community will benefit from it :)

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is how the model will be used deal. Either way may be optimal for the case.

For example - If the model groups applicants into good credit risk and bad credit risk, that might be fine to say model score > x = good risk and model score <= x = bad risk. But maybe there will be differential action based on the model score - like giving a different interest rate or a bigger loan.

In the original example, in regression actual = 191, predicted = 189 you can calculate the loss.

In classification, if actual = 191 and P(>190)=0.35, P(170-190)=0.40, P(150-170)=0.25, then you just know the wrong class. Is that enough for the model usage?

There is also the assumption that a "closer" class will be chosen but that might not be true, e.g actual=191, P(>190)=0.25, P(170-190)=0.25, P(150-170)=0.5. The regression could come up with 160 also but you can measure that loss if the model usage requires it. Many classification algorithms do not know if classes are "close" - [Confusion matrix. "How close I am to the diagonal?". Is there such metric?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/81199/confusion-matrix-how-close-i-am-to-the-diagonal-is-there-such-metric)

You can also look at Ordinal Regression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression. In this case there is an implicit ranking in the "class".

Choose based on how the model will be used. Always important to know the usage and the problem being solved, then work backwards to the model.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! You made a good point regarding the bounds of the ranges. However, I think this could be managed by increasing the classes resolution and/or by using overlapped ranges depending on how the model will be used, don't you think ? Regarding ordinal regression, I don't understand the link with the question, could you please detail ?